# is the std::unique() function broke or something?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++17

I was using the std::unique() function to delete all the duplicates in a vector of int and 
some how there will always be an extra element

```
vec.erase(unique(vec.begin(),vec.end()),vec.end());
```

I looked up [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) and the example also show same kind of behaviour 
it has one duplicate value

[a debug session showing the duplicate elements in the vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVCYd.png)

[sample code from cplusplus.com run on cpp.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyH0e.png)

but when i sorted the vector and tried the unique it worked fine.

is this the some kind of undefined behaviour?

Comment: `std::unique()` works on a sorted range.

Comment: Read the description and not just the examples. It doesn't remove duplicates. It _removes all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements in the range [first,last)._ {1, 0, 1} will stay unchanged. {1, 1, 0} will become {1, 0}.

Comment: Useful reading: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/ and https://blog.plover.com/prog/compiler-error.html. To summarise: It's always your fault.

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique` works on *any* range and removes *consecutive* duplicates (or rather; consecutive *equivalent* elements). This may not be *all* duplicates unless the range is sorted.

This is actually a feature, since you can use the function for more purposes than just removing *all* duplicates - which may not always be what you want (and when it is, you just `std::sort` first).

Answer (score 2):

> is the std::unique() function broke ...

No, it is not broke.

> ... or something?

Yes, something.

> is this the some kind of undefined behaviour?

No.

As per documentation, `std::unique` removes all **adjacent** non-unique elements. If duplicate are not adjacent, then they will remain. If the range is sorted, then all duplicates will be adjacent, and therefore all of them are removed.